# What is the correct configuration for the SQL Server listener with 2 nodes on-prem and 1 node in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, azure, disaster-recovery, listener

I am setting up a 3-node Availability Group with 2 nodes on-premises and the 3rd on a VM in Azure.

All nodes are SQL Server 2019 Enterprise with CU14.  The Availability Group is fine and the listener has been setup using dbatools.io with command below ([reference](https://docs.dbatools.io/Add-DbaAgListener)):

`Add-DbaAgListener -SqlInstance $TargetPrimary -AvailabilityGroup $AGName -Name $ListenerName -IPAddress [available on prem IP],[IP of internal load balancer on Azure] -SubnetMask 255.255.255.0`

I also set the TTL to 120 and `RegisterAllProvidersIP` to 0 since most of the clients can't add the MultiSubnetFailover clause.

(Using a DNN listener is not an option since clients won't be able to specify a non-standard port.)

For the listener connection to work in a DR scenario do I need to follow the instructions for creating the listener on the WSFC [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-load-balancer-portal-configure#step-5-create-the-availability-group-listener-on-the-failover-cluster) instead?

I can't seem to find any clear instructions for the hybrid scenario with Azure as the DR node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For the listener connection to work in a DR scenario do I need to follow the instructions for creating the listener on the WSFC here instead?

Since you only have a single node in Azure and that must be in a different subnet than the other two nodes, thus all you'll need is to add an IP to the listener configuration that can be hosted in the Azure VM subnet. The Azure ILB is only needed to figure out which node in the same subnet is the correct primary since Azure doesn't support ARP which is what Windows Clustering uses to update the other servers to the change.

> I also set the TTL to 120 and RegisterAllProvidersIP to 0 since most of the clients can't add the MultiSubnetFailover clause.

I wish you the best of luck. This isn't going to work well, but if failovers are few and far between it should be fine.